# Optimizing Firebase simultaneous connections to connect to a database instance for only as long as required

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, sharding

My question is about managing simultaneous connections in Firebase Realtime Database. It contains several parts so please bear with me.

We need to add multiple databases to our project and want to know the best approach to enabling/opening and closing connections.

Firebase [suggests](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/usage/sharding#connect_your_app_to_multiple_database_instances) optimizing...

> connections to each database instance by connecting to each database instance for only as long as is necessary.

- Does using the .goOffline() and .goOnline() methods on a database instance **establish** a new connection each time **or temporarily close/free and open** connections? My concern is adding overhead costs (Protocol, SSL, etc).

  **1)** if you connect to a database instance like so:

  ```
  ref = Database.database("https://testapp-1234.firebaseio.com").reference()
  ```

  **2)** then call a `.goOffline()` method on it

  **3)** then again reference to the database later in the app like done in **(1)** will it establish a new connection? Is this an example of ...*frequent, short connections?* My concern coming from this [Link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/usage/billing)
- Further, is this even the right approach to stay connected to a database for as long as is necessary? Which then begs the question if .goOffline() method is even required to close a connection if there are no active listeners or pending write requests for the IOS SDK?

Firebase [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities#section-connection-state) for Android says:

> On Android, Firebase automatically manages connection state to reduce bandwidth and battery usage. When a client has no active listeners, no pending write or onDisconnect operations, and is not explicitly disconnected by the goOffline method, Firebase closes the connection after 60 seconds of inactivity.

- Is this true for IOS as well?